# Java getElementById returning null when passing string with a hyphen or space

Tags: java, jsoup, getelementbyid

I'm having trouble with getElementById returning null when I pass it a variable containing a string such as "blah-blah" or "blah blah".

```
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] parts = line.split("\\*");
            String url = parts[0];
            String element = parts[1];
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            System.out.println(document.getElementById(element));
        }
```

When looping through it is able to print out the correct information when passing a variable with no hyphen/space such as "blahblah" and I've searched for a solution and haven't found anything helpful.

Comment: Space is not a valid char for html id. No idea why it would not work for a hyphen, you will need to provide more info.

Comment: It might be of value to try something like`org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils`.

Comment: I am piping in url and table id data from a text file. The file is formatted as: url[asterisk]tableid where I split the line at the [asterisk] to create url and element variables. When the line looks like example.com[asterisk]exampleid then the program works fine. The error occurs when a line looks like example.com*example-id or something similar.

Comment: Can you place a breakpoint at `String element` when you have such a case? What does `element` show?

Comment: Wow I feel dumb, turns out I'm looking at the table class rather than the table id. Well turns out I created a problem that never existed, thanks for the help haha.

Comment: @helpwithjavapls please consider adding your solution as an answer for further reference.